# How to mock an internal variable with builder

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermock, powermockito

I am writing unit tests and meet a problem with builder:
 Here is the class to be test:

```
public class ToBeTest() {
    public void enact(SomeInput input){
        Session s = Session.builder().attributeA(input.getA()).build();
        s.attributeB("someValue");
    }
}
```

How can I write a test to verify whether Session S set field A and also B successfully? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Basically there are **two** things you can verify on:

- `input.getA()`: mock that instance of `SomeInput` you provide to your code under test, then you can verify that mocked object later on!
- `Session.builder()` is most likely a static call, so use **static** mocking to provide a mocked builder object, which you can verify  later on, too. See the official [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockstatic) for the steps required to do that.

Having said that: your real problem is that you wrote "hard to test code". Surprise, that makes it hard to test. You see, what is the point of having a "method local" Sessions variable in the first place. If that method would *return* that `s`, you could then check if it has certain properties. Or if `s` would be a field of that class, you could then maybe do *other* checking, to ensure that a correctly configured Session was build.

Long story short: PowerMock(ito) offers the things you need to this code. Read some good tutorials and you shouldn't have much issues. *But* it would be worthwhile to also invest into improving your code under test to make it easier to test. My rule of thumb is: when you need PowerMock(ito) to test your code, then your production code should be improved.

Comment: `"hard to test code"` - that's the point. The hidden idea of unit testing is they require a highly testable design, which implies maintainability and clarity. +1